# In my .net core 8 mvc c# project, when I click on the category, the data comes as null listing the products in the relevant category

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, .a

In my .net core 8 mvc c# project, when I click on the category, the data comes as null listing the products in the relevant category.

when clicking on the category of the products listed on the homepage, I cannot list the products in that category, the code I wrote is below

**My Extension**

```
public static string CategorySeoUrl(this Category entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return "";
    }
    if (entity.ParentCategory == null)
    {
        var title = FriendlyURLTitle(entity.Name).ToLower().Replace("--", "-");
        return $"/cat/{title}-C{entity.Id}";
    }
    else
    {
        var title = FriendlyURLTitle(entity.Name).ToLower().Replace("--", "-");
        var Cattitle = FriendlyURLTitle(entity.ParentCategory.Name).ToLower().Replace("--", "-");
        return $"/cat/{Cattitle}-{title}-C{entity.Id}";
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 [Route("cat/{title}-C{id}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Category(long ID)
 {
     var catBlog = await _db.blogPosts.Where(x => x.Id == ID)
         .Include(x => x.Category)
         .Include(x => x.Author)
         .Include(x => x.PostImages)
         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == ID);
     return View(catBlog);
 }
```

`**Url**

```
@Common.Extensions.BlogSeoUrl(Model)
```

**View**

```
@model CategoryViewModel
@using Common
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core;
@using X.PagedList;
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Fluent
@using X.PagedList.Web.Common

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Haber Kategori";
    var pageUrl = Common.Extensions.CategorySeoUrl(Model.Category);
    var urlOrd = Context.Request.Query["order"];
    var qstring = Context.Request.QueryString.DoString();
    var BrandReage = qstring.Contains("categoryID") || qstring == "" ? "?" : "&";
    var pageCategory = qstring.Contains("categoryID") ? $"&categoryID={Context.Request.Query["categoryID"]}" : "";
    var attrs = ViewBag.Attrs as List<Database.BlogAttribute>;
}

@if (@Model.BlogPost.TotalItemCount > 0)
{
    <div class="shop-catalogue grid-view">
        <div class="row row-10 items-grid">
            @{
                if (Model.BlogPost.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.BlogPost)
                    {
                        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("/Views/Partial/_BlogNewsPartial.cshtml", item);
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->
    </div>
    <!-- end grid mode -->
}
else
{
    <div id="divUrunYok" style="width: 100%;">
        <img src="/image/tr.png" style="display: block; margin: 0px auto;" alt="BLOG BULUNMAMAKTADIR">
    </div>
}
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model.BlogPost, _page => $"{pageUrl}?page={_page}{pageCategory}", new PagedListRenderOptions
   {
       LiElementClasses = new string[] { "page-item" },
       PageClasses = new string[] { "page-link" },
       ContainerDivClasses = new string[] { "pagination mt-3 justify-content-center pagination_style1" },
       Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
       //DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true
   })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked in database that same category are there? Or you are not able to fetch in your front end? Have you checked the browser console?

Comment: First thing to check is whether the `ID` property is populated as expected? If not, there's a routing issue.